# Validate a Controlled ReactJs Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hooks

I'm currently using the React Hook Form ( https://react-hook-form.com/ ) to validate my forms, but it happen a strange behavior.

When I click the submit button and the FormInput fullname is empty and I try to write something in, the first letter that I type dosen't appear in the field..

Here the code:

[image]

if I remove the `value={}` this doesn't occur... any idea?

Comment: could you please try with defaultValue ={} instead of value={}

Comment: I tried but if I set defaultValue={user_name} the input starts with the useState("") value.. and dosent change after useEffect() api fetching..

Comment: My bad now it is worked, THANKS!